# Create list of unique substrings in Column by delimiter

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How can I get a List of unique values in my pandas data frame (df) column "OWNER" by the delimiter ";" ? The dtype of OWNER is string.

Thanks a lot! <3

| OWNER |
| --- |
| "A" |
| "B;C" |
| "B;C" |

The Result should be:
unique_value = ["A","B","C"]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get a unique list of strings in pandas after a split() operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23181867/get-a-unique-list-of-strings-in-pandas-after-a-split-operation)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `split` by `';'`, then `explode` and find `unique`s:

```
>>> df = pd.Series(['A', 'B;C', 'B;C'], name='OWNER').to_frame()
>>> df

  OWNER
0     A
1   B;C
2   B;C

>>> df['OWNER'].str.split(';').explode().unique().tolist()
['A', 'B', 'C']
```

Alternatively, you can join the elements by `';'` and then split by the same. Then use `dict.fromkeys` to filter out the duplicates and maintain order, finally convert to a `list`.

```
>>> list(dict.fromkeys(';'.join(df['OWNER']).split(';')))
['A', 'B', 'C']
```